# JS - On yes/no option change check if all 'No' options were selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I check if all 'NO' answers on Yes/No table were chosen, this has to check on each change to any of the Yes/No answers, and then send an alert if all 'NO' were selected

Tried the below but no response seen..

```js
$('.mb-n').change(function(){
  if ($('.mb-n:checked').length == $('.mb-n').length) {
    alert('all no ');
    }  else { alert('all y '); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="mb-odd">
  <td class="mb-prompt"><span>Q1.</span></td>
  <td class="mb-y"><input type="radio" name="123" value="Y" class="{required: true, messages:{required:''}}" rel="" id="123_Y"></td>
  <td class="mb-n"><input type="radio" name="123" value="N" checked="checked" id="123_N" rel=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Well, your code didn't work because there's no `mb-tdevenn` elements in your HTML, so there was nothing for the change event to be bound to.

Comment: Additionally these are radio inputs with the same name. They cannot be checked simultaneously.

Comment: So read the length of the checked and see if it matches the total rows. `$(".mb-n:checked").length === total`

Comment: sorry, edited the element - my mistake.. the radio input with same name is to signify the same question, or that must be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using vanilla JavaScript :

```js
function listenForInputChange ()
{
  // Get all inputs with a NO value and spread them into an array 
  let inputs = [ ...document.querySelectorAll( '.mb-n > input' ) ];

  // Add input event listener on table and listen for change
  document.querySelector( 'table' ).addEventListener( 'input', evt => {

    // if every inputs are checked
    if ( inputs.every( input => input.checked ) )
    {
      // Do something...
      console.log( 'All answers are NO' );
    }

  }, false );
}

listenForInputChange();
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="mb-odd">
  <td class="mb-prompt"><span>Q1.</span></td>
  <td class="mb-y"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Y"></td>
  <td class="mb-n"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="N" checked></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr class="mb-even">
  <td class="mb-prompt"><span>Q2.</span></td>
  <td class="mb-y"><input type="radio" name="q2" value="Y"></td>
  <td class="mb-n"><input type="radio" name="q2" value="N" checked></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="mb-odd">
  <td class="mb-prompt"><span>Q3.</span></td>
  <td class="mb-y"><input type="radio" name="q3" value="Y"></td>
  <td class="mb-n"><input type="radio" name="q3" value="N" checked></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This worked very well, since i had different classes for odd and even rows, i used two input vars, then used both for the condition.. thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the `radio` is `checked`, not if the `td` is checked (`<td>` doesn't have a `checked` property).

I made some adjustments to your code, including modifications in HTML, that was a little bit weird. I added a similar class to all radio buttons and a similar class to all YES radios and NO radios, that way you'll have a much better control over what is selected and what is not.

Check below

```js
$('.radioBtn').change(function(){
  if ($('.radioNo:checked').length == $('.mb-n').length) {
    console.log('all no');
  } else if ($('.radioYes:checked').length == $('.mb-y').length){ 
    console.log('all yes'); 
  }else{
    console.log("Some Yes and some No")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="mb-odd">
    <td class="mb-prompt"><span>Q1.</span></td>  
    <td class="mb-y">
      <input type="radio" name="123" value="Y" class="radioBtn radioYes" id="123_Y">YES
    </td>
    <td class="mb-n">
      <input type="radio" name="123" value="N" class="radioBtn radioNo" checked id="123_N" >NO
    </td>  
  </tr>
  <tr class="mb-odd">
    <td class="mb-prompt"><span>Q2.</span></td>
    <td class="mb-y">
      <input type="radio" name="1234" value="Y" class="radioBtn radioYes" id="1234_Y">YES
    </td>
    <td class="mb-n">
      <input type="radio" name="1234" value="N" class="radioBtn radioNo" checked id="1234_N" >NO
    </td>  
  </tr>
  <tr class="mb-odd">
    <td class="mb-prompt"><span>Q3.</span></td>
    <td class="mb-y">
      <input type="radio" name="12345" value="Y" class="radioBtn radioYes" id="12345_Y">YES
    </td>
    <td class="mb-n">
      <input type="radio" name="12345" value="N" class="radioBtn radioNo" checked id="12345_N" >NO
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Took me awhile to get up and running, however alot of change needed on my front. I've given the best answer @sphinxplayer because it was literally a copy & paste job. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every row in the table has a checkbox you should be able to do it like this without changing anything in your setup:

```
$('.mb-n').change(function(){
   if ($("table").find("tr").length == $(".mb-n > input[type='radio']:checked").length)
       window.alert("Oh noes...");
});
```